# Maximum repeating sequence instead of longest repeating sequence

Tags: java, string, dynamic-programming

I am trying to get the most repeated sequence of characters in a string. 
For example :

**Input:**

```
s = "abccbaabccba"
```

**Output:**

```
 2
```

I have used dynamic programming to figure out the repeating sequence, but this returns the longest repeating character sequence. For example:

**Input:**

```
s = "abcabcabcabc"
```

**Output:**

```
2   
2(abcabc,abcabc) instead of 4(abc,abc,abc,abc)
```

Here is the part of the code where I'm filling the DP table and extracting repeating sequence. Can anyone suggest how I can get the most repeating sequence?

```
 //Run through the string and fill the DP table.
        char[] chars = s.toCharArray();
        for(int i = 1; i <= length; i++){
            for(int j = 1; j <= length; j++){
                if( chars[i-1] == chars[j-1] && Math.abs(i-j) > table[i-1][j-1]){
                    table[i][j] = table[i-1][j-1] + 1;
                    if(table[i][j] > max_length_sub){
                        max_length_sub = table[i][j];
                        array_index = Math.min(i, j);
                    }
                }else{
                    table[i][j] = 0;
                }
            }               
        }       
        //Check if there was a repeating sequence and return the number of times it occurred.
        if( max_length_sub > 0 ){
            String temp = s;
            String subSeq = "";
            for(int i = (array_index - max_length_sub); i< max_length_sub; i++){
                subSeq = subSeq + s.charAt(i);
            }
            System.out.println( subSeq );
            Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(subSeq);
            Matcher  matcher = pattern.matcher(s);
            int count = 0;
            while (matcher.find())
                count++;

            // To find left overs - doesn't seem to matter 
            String[] splits = temp.split(subSeq);
            if (splits.length == 0){
                return count;
            }else{
                return 0;
            }
        }
```

Comment: I assume this is an assignment. Are you **required** to use DP for solution? are you allowed Java Collections?

Comment: Yeah! We are not required to use DP. And yes, I can use java collections

Answer (score 1):

Simple and dump, the the smallest sequence to be considered is a pair of characters (*):

- loop over the whole String an get every consecutive pair of characters, like using a `for` and `substring` to get the characters;
- count the occurrence of that pair in the String, create a method `countOccurrences()` using `indexof(String, int)` or regular expressions; and
- store the greatest count, use one variable `maxCount` outside the loop and an `if` to check if the actual count is greater (or `Math.max()`)

(*) if "abc" occurs 5 times, than "ab" (and "bc") will occur at least 5 times too - so it is enough to search just for "ab" and "bc", not need to check "abc"

**Edit** without leftovers, see comments, summary:

- check if the first character is repeated over the whole string, if not
- check if the 2 initial characters are repeated all over, if not
- check if the 3 ...

at least 2 counters/loops needed: one for the number of characters to test, second for the position being tested. Some arithmetic could be used to improve performance: the length of the string must be divisible by the number of repeated characters without remainder.

Comment: Actually, I posted half the problem. Let me put up the problem. "A cake is round, and decorated with M&Ms in a circle around the edge. But while the rest of the cake is uniform, the M&Ms are not: there are multiple colors, and every minion must get exactly the same sequence of M&Ms. You also want to make sure you can serve the entire cake. To help you best cut the cake, you have turned the sequence of colors of the M&Ms on the cake into a string: each possible letter (between a and z) corresponds to a unique color."

Comment: "Write a function called answer(s) that, given a non-empty string less than 200 characters in length describing the sequence of M&Ms, returns the maximum number of equal parts that can be cut from the cake without leaving any leftovers." - This is the complete problem statement.

Comment: I don't know if checking for sequence pair would work for this problem!

Comment: @hema begur - does not work for **this** problem , but should work for the one asked in the question - this is the first time you mention "without leaving any leftovers", a totally different problem than asked before >:-{

Comment: Sorry about not posting the complete question. I used a technique similar to what you suggested. Like, if the string is abcabc, I'm trying to find no of occurrences of each suffix (suffixes being a,ab,abc,abca,abcab,abcabc). I used (lengthOfSuffix * countOfSuffix == lenOfString) to check for leftovers. Do you think if we can use DP, that'd give a better time complexity? Because this is at least O(n^2). And I'm using Regex to find no of occurrences of all suffixes, I'm not sure what time this would take, if finding substring matches takes  O(n^2), the algo which I've used above becomes O(n^3)